# How to lock an active row from being changed in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, locking, row

I have just joined the stackoverflow forum because I was struggling to fix an issue with locking a row in Excel using VBA.
 Basiclly what is needed to be done is when a row has  been filled up it automatically  locks itself from being changed in the future.
 I have used the following **code** :

```
N = Target.Row
If Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Not Target.Value >= 1 Then Exit Sub
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("A" & N & ":K" & N).Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

The active row is being succesfully locked but I recieve an **error message** :

```
Apllication-defined or object-defined error
```

I couldnt figure out what is the cause of that error. Please help!

P.S. the code is inserted in a `big Sub Worksheet_change`.

Comment: On which line are you receiving the error?

Comment: After filling in the row and selecting a value from a dropdown box for "H" the current row locks. But when I try to enter data I receive the above error.

Answer (score 0):

All Cells on a Worksheet are Locked by default.  So, when you apply `ActiveSheet.Protect` you will effectively Lock all cells

You will need to UnLock all cells either in your potential UsedRange, or the whole worksheet, before the Worksheet_Change event activates and before the Worksheet is protected.  This is a one-off operation.

To see this and manually unlock the cells, select a Range and, have a look at Home > Cells > Format > Format Cells...; otherwise you can unlock the cells in code, see [reference here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836172%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Barry!

I have done that and am still getting the error:

Apllication-defined or object-defined error

Comment: With this mod your code is working for me without a code error.  As Mark has requested on which code line are you getting the error

Comment: The thing is that I am getting the error when I try to modify a cell which is not in the locked range and have the sheet protected.

I.e. I have selected a value greater than 1 in Col H, that locks the current row and when i try to modify a cell on the next row I get the error. I hope I have been detailed enough.

Comment: Like I said works for me and you still haven't said at what line the error occurs!  Perhaps post the full code of your Worksheet_Change Sub for us to look at.